# Convert string to Moment object

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have this weird problem with momentjs. I have a input which has a date in a string, to fill this input I used:

```
var result1 = moment(this._d).format("L")
```

Now I need to read this value and convert it to a moment object again:

```
var result2 = moment(result1 , "L")
```

Well, I think everything should be ok, but somewhere im loosing the date... The result2 is a date of 01-01-0000

Check this simple test to see what I mean:

```
moment(this._d).format("L") ==> "20-01-1900"
moment(moment(this._d).format("L"), "L").format("L") ==> "01-01-0000"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using version 2.0.0, just tried with version 2.4.0 and this doesnt happen.